# Is atrpms dead?

Tags: yum, repository, scientific-linux

I have used atrpms repo before, but recently I am getting this error whenever I try to update or install something `http://dl.atrpms.net/el6Server-x86_64/atrpms/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://dl.atrpms.net/el6Server-x86_64/atrpms/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'connect() timed out!')`. I checked http://dl.atrpms.net/ and that gives timed out error. Does anyone know if that repo has moved anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just checked [one of their mirrors](http://ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de/Mirrors/atrpms/dl.atrpms.net/) and the last update there seems to be from December 2014, for Fedora 20 packages. But I didn't find any recent news that it might be down for everybody. Right now their servers seem to time out on connection requests.

If you only require some older packages from them (only el6 ?) then you could easily switch the repo configuration `/etc/yum.repos.d/atrpms.repo` to any of the mirrors, like the one mentioned above or this one: https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.atrpms.net/

Answer (score 3):

> Short Answer - Yes.
>
> You can use Is It Down Right Now? to check the status of any website.
>
> > "Is It Down Right Now" monitors the status of your favorite web sites and checks whether they are down or not. Check a website status easily by using the below test tool. Just enter the url and a fresh site status test will be performed on the domain name in real time using our online website checker tool. For detailed information, check response time graph and user comments.
>
> http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/atrpms.net.html:
>
> > Atrpms.net is DOWN for everyone. It is not just you. The server is not responding...
>
> See also this question [Is atrpms dead?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229661/is-atrpms-dead)

Answer taken from superuser.com: https://superuser.com/questions/974366/is-the-atrpms-net-repository-offline
all credits go to @DavidPostill